# redirection on server side depending on client's display size

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script>
var winw = window.innerWidth;
if (winw < 640) {location.href='minw.php';}
</script>
```

I have the above code inside the `head` tag of my page.

The intention is to prevent display the page on screens below 640px and redirect the user on a specific page with a short info about the requirement.

But the page is still starting to load and after a pair of seconds the redirection happens.

Is it possible somehow to tell the server what is the size of client's display and make the redirection on server (php) side, before any output of original page?

Comment: you need to put this code inside `$('window').load(function(){..});` and `$('window').reasize(function(){..});`

Comment: Really if you have to do this (which there should be no reason to do, and its only going to annoy the user) is to use javascript to overlay a message at that size instead of redirecting. Most people like to do multiple things on a single screen so you should make it responsive not dictate'ive ;p

Comment: There is no any way to get client's window size on the server with 1st request. Client may have no screen at all (curl etc)

Comment: What you want, is called _Client Hints_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation, http://httpwg.org/http-extensions/client-hints.html (not really production-ready yet though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what are you trying to do, and you want to do it with PHP. Although my home is PHP but what about doing it with client side styles? `CSS` is here for things like this, doing this at the server side means you have to send the client display width with every request!. I will definitely do style things with "cascading *style* sheets" not a server side programming

Expand this snippet to see the effect.

```css
div#mainContent{
  display:block;
}
div#screenNote{
  display:none;
  color:red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    div#mainContent{
      display:none;
    }
    div#screenNote{
      display:block;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent">
<h1>This is our site home page (you have  ascreen wider than 640px)</h1>
</div>
<div id="screenNote">
  <h1>Sorry for any inconvenience, our site does not suppor responsive design yet. you can view page only with 640px display or wider</h1>
</div>
```